# REST: deleting a resource from a collection using an implied ID as an input

Tags: rest, http

I have a resource:

`/items`

I want to allow users to vote on this resource both up and down

`POST /items/{item_id}/votes` - to create a new vote passing in their + or - vote

I can get votes by (it uses logged in user's ID from access token to store votes with a key `[item_id, user_id]`):

`GET /items/{item_id}/votes` - to get all votes on an item

`GET /items/{item_id}/upvotes` - to get all up votes on an item

`GET /items/{item_id}/downvotes` - to get all down votes on an item

So `votes` is a collection, but if I want to delete a vote completely should I use:

`DELETE /items/{id}/votes` ?? and delete based ont eh user's ID - but this resource refers to the collection I don't want to delete the whole collection, I do have enough info with the user_id and item_id to delete the vote but it doesn't seem right to me.

I can't directly refer to the user's vote at the moment so should I add an ID to each vote and:

`DELETE /items/{item_id}/votes/{vote_id}`

or maybe just:

`DELETE /votes/{vote_id)`

OR maye I don't need an ID on the vote and I can use:

`DELETE /item/{item_id}/votes/mine/` -  to delete an item from the collection using my logged in user_id

So to sumarise; what is the proper way to delete an item from a collection using REST via HTTP methods?

**UPDATE**

I have a feeling that these are the best solution

`POST /items/{item_id}/votes` - to create a new vote using item_id and user_id (from access token)

`DELETE /item/{item_id}/votes/mine/` -  to delete my vote using item_id and user_id (from access token)

Comment: @Ray it's not strictly the same as currently my votes don't have a UUID meaning that there isn't actually a way to GET an individual vote therefore not a way to DELETE an actual vote, the index on votes is implied by the user's logged in ID, I could delete *my* votes using `DELETE /item/{item_id}/votes/mine/` with th eimplied user id. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I see, your vote id's are not uuid's.  I'd vote for avoiding  `DELETE /item/{item_id}/votes/mine/`.  Use the `DELETE /items/{item_id}/votes/{vote_id}` if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on how your collection looks like, but I assume if a vote is a downvote, it appears both in the `downvotes` collection and in the `votes` collection.

Both of these collections should link to this one vote, and ideally the vote (despite appearing in 2 collections) should have the same url in both.

To conform with REST you *should* indeed give the specific vote resource a specific url. If `/items/{item_id}/votes/{vote_id}` is the unique path to the vote, `DELETE` that and (as you said) not the collection.

So your other example:

```
DELETE /votes/{vote_id)
```

is *also* fine. If this is a globally unique vote_id, then that resource can still appear in post-specific `downvotes`, `upvotes` and `votes` collections.

But this:

```
DELETE /item/{item_id}/votes/mine/
```

I personally would probably avoid. It's not super wrong, but the fact that you need `mine` to appear in the url probably means your client is manually constructing the url and not discovering it. The actual url is mostly irrelevant.

**Responding to your UPDATE**

You also mention that every vote is tied to a "user_id". This means that you don't even need `POST` to first create the vote. Just give the client the correct 'voting' url and `PUT` your new vote resource. (remember that `PUT` is generally better for creating resources because it's idempotent. `POST` is typically only useful in cases where the new resource url cannot be determined by a client).

So these are the steps I would take:

1. A client has access to the item via `/items/{item_id}`
2. that item should have a link to `/items/{item_id}/votes/{user_id}`.
3. The client uses that link to `PUT` or `DELETE` a vote.

Comment: I never considered that the ID could be anything other than just a resources UUID, the fact that I can use `/votes/{user_id}` has just blown my mind...

Comment: As you can see from this comment I wrote "my votes don't have a UUID meaning that there **isn't actually a way to GET an individual vote**", when there clearly is! The penny has dropped lol thank you.

Comment: Also your comment about "Both of these collections should link to this one vote" was true there was one (and the same) vote in two collections, made me think that there should only be one collection and getting up and down votes should be handled by a query param appended to the URI, I think that you would agree that this is the better option, is this correct?

Comment: @Neilos no I think having 3 collections and using a query parameter is pretty much the same thing. So just pick what you prefer. Just remember that a collection like `/foo/col1` can totally contain items such as `/foo/col2/abc`. They don't need to be in some sort of hierarchy